# Hp ProBook - upon boot up screen is black, does not wake

Tags: 16.04, radeon, monitor, fglrx, catalyst

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

After a fresh install on my laptop.

Black screen on boot, no cursor, screen is off. I have to force close, then powering up for the second time the system will boot up fine.

**MODEL**: HP ProBook 6475b

**GRAPHICS**: Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)

**CPU**: AMD A4-4300M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2

Radeon HD 7420G

Downloaded the latest Radeon driver, however I get the following error:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Laptop001:~$ sudo sh amd-driver-installer-14.20-x86.x86_64.run
[sudo] password for pst007x: 
Created directory fglrx-install.e3sJRY
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-14.20.......................................................................................................................................................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.18.4_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer 1.18.4_64a:none:4.4.0-43-generic:)
Installation will not proceed.

Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.e3sJRY
```

Upgraded open drivers: [LINK](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) but same issue on boot.

Answer (score 0):

This an issue with your discrete GPU, the most simple solution is try to switch your Graphics mode in BIOS to integrated.

Perhaps most appropriate is to try to build and install the fglrx catalyst drivers.

More info about AMD Graphics: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD